# quite different results in spatialEco::tpi with circular and rectangular window

Tags: r, elevation, tpi

In R, I have an elevation raster. I want to calculate the topogographic position index using the `spatialEco::tpi` function. The CRS of the elevation raster is "+init=epsg:5677"; the CRS unit thus should be "meter". The resolution of the elevation raster is

```
> raster::res (elevation_raster)
[1] 20.9 30.9
```

This is the elevation raster:
[image]

`spatialEco::tpi` with `win = "rectangle"`  and `scale = 5` should yield similar results as `spatialEco::tpi` with `win = "circle"` and `scale = 150`. At least, I thought so, because 5 * 30 = 150. However, I get completely different values and the plots also look quite different:

```
spatialEco::tpi (elevation_raster, win = "rectangle", scale = 5)
```

[image]

```
spatialEco::tpi (elevation_raster, win = "circle", scale = 150)
```

[image]

Notice that the two plots look quite different but also that there is a huge difference in the value ranges. Apparently, I am missing something here. However, I have no clue what. Perhaps someone can give a proper explanation?

Comment: I an laid up with a broken leg at the moment so it will be a few days  before I can take a look. As I recall the focal function was not honoring a circular focal window and I came up with a workaround, it could be that it is no longer a germaine solution and needs to be fixed. For the moment stick with a rectangular window as I am sure the issue is comming from the circular focal window.

Comment: Hi Jeffrey, all the best for your leg then. I appreciate your answer very much. Of course I am looking forward to a more ample answer. For now, I will stick to the rectangular window.